# How to Get Two Separate Siblings with XPath

Tags: json, xml, jenkins, xpath

I am trying to invoke Jenkins XML API to retrieve specific set of information from its REST endpoint (`...` indicates that there are similar sibling elements in the content but excluded for brevity):

```
<workflowRun _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun">
   <action _class="hudson.model.CauseAction">
      <cause _class="hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause">
         <shortDescription>Started by timer</shortDescription>
      </cause>
   </action>
   <action _class="hudson.model.ParametersAction">
      <parameter _class="hudson.model.StringParameterValue">
         <name>projectName</name>
         <value>My-Proj</value>
      </parameter>
      <parameter _class="hudson.model.StringParameterValue">
         <name>NodeParam</name>
         <value>UY-DO1</value>
      </parameter>
      ...
   </action>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <action _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl"/>
   <action/>
   <action _class="hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction">
      <failCount>21</failCount>
      <skipCount>6</skipCount>
      <totalCount>223</totalCount>
      <urlName>myReport</urlName>
   </action>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <action _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"/>
   <action/>
   <action/>
   <building>false</building>
   ...
   <result>FAILURE</result>
   <timestamp>1553145960340</timestamp>
   ...
</workflowRun>
```

I am interested in obtaining the following information only:

```
   <action _class="hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction">
      <failCount>21</failCount>
      <skipCount>6</skipCount>
      <totalCount>223</totalCount>
      <urlName>myReport</urlName>
   </action>       
   <timestamp>1553145960340</timestamp>
```

However, I cannot find an XPath command to grab all this data in one go. I can run two separate calls to retrieve the needed information but that requires two separate server trips. I was wondering if there is an XPath command I can use to retrieve the targeted `<action>` and `<timestamp>` in one go:

```
https://jenkins_host/job/MyApp/job/Some_Jenkins_Job/lastCompletedBuild/api/xml?xpath=/workflowRun/action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']
```

Which gets us:

```
   <action _class="hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction">
      <failCount>21</failCount>
      <skipCount>6</skipCount>
      <totalCount>223</totalCount>
      <urlName>myReport</urlName>
   </action>
```

and timestamp separately (note a switch from `xpath` to `tree`):

```
https://jenkins_host/job/MyApp/job/Some_Jenkins_Job/lastCompletedBuild/api/xml?tree=timestamp
```

with the outcome of:

```
<workflowRun _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun">
   <timestamp>1553145960340</timestamp>
</workflowRun>
```

I have tried to use a combination of `tree` and `xpath` but getting errors:

```
https://jenkins_host/job/MyApp/job/Some_Jenkins_Job/lastCompletedBuild/api/xml?tree=timestamp&xpath=/workflowRun/action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']
```

Seems like they can't be mixed up. I even tried using this at no avail:

```
xml?xpath=/workflowRun/action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']&/workflowRun/timestamp
```

or

```
xml?xpath=/workflowRun/action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']&xpath=/workflowRun/timestamp
```

Any idea how I can get both set of data with a single XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next one is a perfectly valid XPath 1.0 expression, but I don't know whether your REST endpoint can or cannot parse it...

```
/workflowRun
   /action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']
|/workflowRun
   /action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']
      /following-sibling::timestamp[1]
```

Or without union (forced to use the Kaysian method):

```
/workflowRun
   /*[self::action/@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction' or
      self::timestamp[
         count(.|../action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']/following-sibling::timestamp[1]) 
         = count(../action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']/following-sibling::timestamp[1])
     ]]
```

The key in both is to select the reference element (the `action`) and then following sibling `timestamp` **and not just every** `timestamp`.

Comment: Thank you. I had to update your answer a bit to get it to work, but the core of solution pretty much resolves this question.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, union grouped expressions through by one of operators: `|` or `or`. Choose one of this solutions:

1. `|`-operator:

`(//action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']/descendant-or-self::*)|//timestamp`

2. `or`-operator:

   `//*[self::action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction'] or self::timestamp]/descendant-or-self::*`

Comment: Do note that `//action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']/descendant-or-self::*` is the same as `//action[@_class='hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction']//*`. Although I dont't know where that came from. Not from the question.

Comment: Nope, expression `action//*` is not return a self-node, but author want to get this `action`-node

Comment: You are right. You will lose the `self` axe. But why you select `action` and descendant is no clear from the question.